# hmac init with iv value different from default in java

Tags: java, cryptography, hmac, javax

I'm trying to calculate HMAC with iv (without any additional key).
I need to pass it at the 'init' level. I know that usually there is no need in passing the iv, since there are default ivs for hmac/sha. But if I don't want to use the defaults, and want to supply *my own iv* how is it possible to implement in java? I've tried using javax, but it's MAC init accepts only the signing key.

For example:

```
Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
byte[] hmacKeyBytes = key.getBytes();
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(hmacKeyBytes, "HmacSHA1");
hmac.init(secretKey);
```

- I want to init with some iv value. But don't know how.

I'm referring to initial value used to start the hash/hmac iterated process. Usually it is some arbitrary number, not exposed to the user. I want to be able to change this default initialization vector for hash functions/ find some way to supply my own iv. How can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: It is totally unclear why one would want to do that, what is the advantage?

Comment: It allows to create a custom algorithm, similar to HMAC-SHA1, without the need of finding an open source implementation of one, and modifying it.

Comment: How would this IV enter the algorithm? Adding some bytes to the key or to the message just has the same effect.

Comment: You mean that if I concatenate the iv to the plaintext, I will have the same outcome as if I've begun with my own iv at the first place?

Comment: More or less yes. HMAC does not use an IV so one cannot say where it would go.

Comment: Be aware of creating your own algorithm, you shall know what are you doing to keep your MAC safe (collision resistant, good avalanche effect, resistant to linear analysis, etc).  Appending/prepending IV ( random known plain message) would randomize the output. IV is mostly used for encryption. What is your reason for using IV for HMAC?

Comment: If you're using HMAC to authenticate a ciphertext, then you **must** apply it to the IV as well. (See solution below. I wrote a little pseudocode ... if you post your encryption code, I'll help you work it into a working example.)

Answer (score 1):

The HMAC takes the initial parameter only the key. Effectively - the same content should have the same authentication tag, so IV is not needed/desired by definition.

As far I recall from my cryptography classes having non-static IV would lead to vulnerabilities with MAC/HMAC for some algorithm implementations, but I don't recall details anymore (you could ask in the Cryptography section of the stackoverflow https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

If you really want having a sort of IV, you can still prepend the IV to the content.

Answer (score 0):

HMAC-SHA1 is called a **message authentication code ([MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code))**. This object takes as input a key *K*, and an arbitrary-length message *X*, and outputs a **tag** *T*. Basically, a MAC is secure if it's hard to find a new input *X* and a tag *T* such that HMAC-SHA1(*K*, *M*) = *T*, for an unknown key *K*.

My guess is that you're wondering what to do with the IV, because you're ushing HMAC-SHA1 with some sort of encryption scheme? AES-CTR encryption, for example, uses an IV. In this case, **you must encrypt the ciphertext and IV.** So in pseudocode:

```
(IV, C) := AES-CTR(K1, M) # Maybe the output is a string with the IV prepended
T := HMAC-SHA1(K2, (IV, C))
return (IV, C, T)
```

By the way, HMAC-SHA1 is [no longer considered secure](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html). Consider using something like HMAC-SHA256.